# Is this a bug for Microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsZ6E.png)I send a query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=displayName,securityIdentifier
in Microsoft graph API explorer,
and receive the internal server error
{
"error": {
"code": "Service_InternalServerError",
"message": "Encountered an internal server error.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-09-18T17:21:58",
"request-id": "e1703cb6-022f-4a9f-ac47-21683298f468",
"client-request-id": "e1703cb6-022f-4a9f-ac47-21683298f468"
}
}
}

Is this a known bug?[error response from explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsZ6E.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is being investigated. We hope to reach out to you soon with an answer

Comment: any updates? I also faced with same errors in my tenant - sometimes the same request returns data, but sometimes I got this error....